# How to make an object visible in scope of entire controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i need to get instantiate an object which requires parameters. I also need this object to be available in the scope of the entire controller once instantiated. How can this be done?

Edit: some code to help illustrate

```
def beginLoad(user, category)
  #stuff
  @gaobj = GraphAssistant.new(@arrays.fetch(0), @arrays.fetch(1))
  values = @gaobj.externalize
  ret = {"axis_label" => values.fetch(0), "out" => values.fetch(1), "i" => values.fetch(2)}
end
```

But when I try to call it again from this method:

```
def resumeLoad(direction)
  if direction.eql? "left"
    @gaobj.decrementPosition
  elsif direction.eql? "right"
    @gaobj.incrementPosition
  end
  #other stuff
end
```

it doesnt work. I suppose I could do all of this logic in the view, what implications will that have on performance though?

Comment: I guess `resumeLoad` is called in the next request, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, @PaulSchreiber has suggested that '@x' will not be persisted to the session, this is probably the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefix it with an @sign: `@foo = Foo.new`.

Update: Sounds like you need this persisted to the session.

At the end of beginLoad, add:

```
session[:foo] = @foo
```

At the beginning of resumeLoad, add:

```
@foo = session[:foo]
```

Comment: I've done this. It give me a nil class when I try to make method calls on the object from a different method in the controller.

Comment: What happens in between beginLoad and resumeLoad? Do you render content to the user? ivars aren't automatically persisted to the session.

Comment: Yes, I do. What I am going to try now is creating a module that simply stores objects in a hashmap. Then I should be able to access them, perform an operation and restore. I put it in a module as I have an existing one that assists with rendering content for this page and I can append it to that and use it multiple times throughout the project. If there is a better way of persisting these ivars though please let me know.

Comment: I updated my answer to explain how to persist this to the session.

Comment: Thanks, I did that, except I had to change it slightly (to user_session[:foo]) as I am using devise authentication. Unfortunately this throws an error undefined method 'nil' for nil.class error. This happens to me when I try to access the current_user from any controller method that is not show, index, create etc... I didn't know that error carried through to sessions. V. frustrating. What you said would usually be the answer though..

Answer (score 0):

If both of those functions are being called from the same controller action, the instance variable (`@gaobj`) should be accessible to both.  You will need to make sure that `#beginLoad` is called before `#resumeLoad` for *every* incoming request.  Is that the problem?

Comment: Its not possible to call resumeLoad before beginLoad.